# Is there an iPhone SE simulator for Xcode 11, iOS 13?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode11, iphone-se

I'm running Xcode 11.0 on macOS Mojave (10.14.6) and though the iPhone SE is [officially supported on iOS 13](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210327), it doesn't appear in the list of simulators.

[image]

It can't be added nor downloaded, as far as I can see.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Xcode 11 doesn't automatically add every possible simulator. But you can add an iPhone SE iOS 13 simulator.

In Xcode, click on the Window menu and select Devices and Simulators. Select the Simulators tab. Tap the + in the bottom-left corner. Give the new simulator a name. Select iPhone SE as the device type. Enter iOS 13 as the OS Version.

Now you have what you need.

**Edit:** This is still valid with XCode 12.3 and iOS 14.3 as of January 2020

Comment: Correct, we deliberately don't create every supported device to keep the list smaller. You can also use `xcrun simctl create` from the command line to create simulators.

Comment: In my Xcode 11.2 "Window - Devices and Simulators - Simulators" displays a long list of simulators, including one for the iPhone SE but it doesn't seem to change anything about which of them are shown in the list op posted a screenshot of.

Comment: @Neph Perhaps you should post your own question with all relevant details about the issue you are having.

Comment: @rmaddy It's the same question as op's - as the desired simulator is missing in the list - and would probably get marked/closed as duplicate.

Comment: @rmaddy I answered my own question as you said but you closed it as duplicate. Your answer doesn't work for me though, plus I need it to work for IOS 12.4, not iOS 13, so could you please open my question again.

Comment: @russbishop, I can understand wanting to keep the list small, but having the SE (first gen) on there seems critical so that developers think to test with the 4" devices.

Comment: This works also with XCode 12.3, I could add an iPhone SE 1st generation running iOS 14.3. Great!

Answer (score 1):

Also can be useful. The problem may be in your project preferences. If downloading simulators didn't work, try this. Open you project in Xcode -> Choose your project on the Navigator which is on the left side
[Navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iFfF.png)

Then in the Deployment Info in target tab choose IOS version for your project (choose 10 or 11 for all simulator displaying)

[Deployment Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g77P9.png)

Comment: Hey Thanks this worked for me. I tried above all but forgot to set deployment target the previous versions.