# ios simulator missing devices after macOS update

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Many devices are missing in iOS simulator after macOS update (macOS Mojave 10.14.6, the latest update).

6s, 7, X and other devices are missing.

How to restore or get this devices back to list (for iOS 13)?

[image]

Comment: Just add whatever simulators you think you need. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58071781/is-there-an-iphone-se-simulator-for-xcode-11-ios-13/58071815#58071815

Comment: There's no need to add a 6s or 7. The iPhone 8 simulator is the same thing as those.

Comment: Thanks, but I just can't add whatever simulators I need. All other devices I need (6s, 7, 8) available for iOS 12.2 version only. So, I can't select those devices with iOS 13. Also I can't download or add those devices for iOS 13 manually, there is no such option. The only way is to use 12.2 iOS version with full device list support. Are you sure that 6s, 7 and 8 iPhones have same screen dimension?

Comment: Yes, the 6, 6s, 7, 7s, 8, and 8s are all the same screen size. And the 6s and later all support iOS 13. But if you want to test iOS 12 simulators, then download the iOS 12 simulator through Xcode -> Preferences -> Components

Comment: Some misunderstanding occurred, unfortunately. I need to use 6s, 7 devices with 13 iOS but there is no way to add these devices in preferences (exactly for 13 iOS).

Comment: Assuming you are using Xcode 11, see the link in my first comment for how to add the missing simulators.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the device you want.
In the simulator:

In the topbar:

```
choose -> Hardware
choose -> Device
choose -> Manage Devices
choose -> Simulators (above, in the middle)
choose -> + (left beneath)
select the device AND the IOS-version you want.
choose -> Create
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In 2022,
When opened to XCode on top bar,
-> Window -> Devices and Simulators -> Simulators
left bottom of the window, you can find '+' button and you can add which one you want, you can add...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).