# Can't add iPhone SE (1st generation) simulator to Xcode 11

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode11

When I go to "Add Additional Simulators - Devices and Simulators - Simulators" there's a long list of simulators, including iPhone SE (1st generation). But when I close this window it doesn't appear in the simulators available for running. Tried to add another one manually, but it only appears in that list in "Devices and Simulators", not in the dropdown menu in the upper left corner.

Comment: The iPhone SE (1st Gen) is way old. It has left the simulator group in Xcode 12, but I can double check for Xcode 11. Did you mean to say SE (2nd Gen)?

Comment: The iPhone SE (1st Gen) is old, but it still supports iOS 13. And I know people who still use it. So it's important to check how the layout looks on that tiny screen :) The point is – iPhone SE (1st Gen) is shown on the list of simulators in settings, but I can't get it to appear in the dropdown menu of simulators before running.

Comment: @0-1 so your apps don't support small screens? :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an iPhone SE simulator for Xcode 11, iOS 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58071781/is-there-an-iphone-se-simulator-for-xcode-11-ios-13)

Comment: @Chris yes, thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can add easily:

Window > Devices and Simulators > Simulators
On the left is a list of installed Simulators
Each Simulator can be marked as "Show as run destination"
At the bottom-left is a "+" icon, to add new simulators
Simulator name
Device Type
OS Version
OS Version > Download more simulator runtimes...