# Flutter sign in with Apple not working on iOS simulator (infinite loader)

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-simulator, apple-sign-in

I'm using [sign_in_with_apple](https://pub.dev/packages/sign_in_with_apple#server). Have an issue on iOS simulator (software version 14.0). Infinite loader is displayed after a password is entered and 'Continue' is tapped. The flow gets stuck. Nothing happens next. What could be the reason for that? What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Looks like it's related to https://github.com/aboutyou/dart_packages/issues/144

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Looks like currently there is an issue on iOS 14 simulator . Need to use a real device or an iOS 13 simulator. See https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651533.

Comment: for me it does not work on iOS 13 simulator also

Comment: @KamenDobrev enable "Sign in with Apple" capability in xcode; enable "Sign in with Apple" capability for the bundle id (from https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list); re-download provisioning profile if using manual code signing

Comment: how to change the iOS to iOS 13?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58071815/10417992 for changing to iOS 13 @Azhar

Comment: works well on 13.7

Comment: It apparently works with iOS 16 simulator and XCode 14 RC

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew said, the issue is with iOS 14.0 simulator. Unfortunately it hasn't been solved in iOS 15.0 either.
I will suggest the same solution as Andrew but would explain a bit more about the details.

1. Download iOS 13.0 emulator. BY default you will only have latest one, for example iOS 15.0, Go to Xcode. Tope left, click on xcode, then preferences, then click on components. Download the iOS 13.0 emulator.
2. Click onto runner home page, go to general(beside sign in and capabilities). Under deployment info, check 13.0 iOS version.
3. Go to your pod file and paste/edit this snippet at the end

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
    end
  end
end
```

This will set up all your configs to the required iOS 13.0 version.

Other requirements

- Make sure you have a developer apple account set up

If you followed everything till now, it should all run well.